# Convergence exercise related to improper integral

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I'm doing the following exercise in mathematical analysis: (about improper integral)

Let $f\in C^1(0,1]$ be a continuously differentiable function on the half interval $(0,1]$. Suppose $f$　is nonnegative everywhere and $\int_0^1 x|f'(x)|dx<+\infty$. Prove:$\int_0^1 f(x)dx<+\infty$.

So of course I think the idea is to use integration by parts: $\int x f'(x) dx=xf(x)-\int f(x)dx$, so
$$\int_\epsilon ^1 x f'(x) dx=f(1)-\epsilon f(\epsilon)-\int_\epsilon ^1 f(x)dx.$$
Now it's time for $\epsilon \rightarrow 0+$, but I can't deal with $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0+}\epsilon f(\epsilon)$. Can anyone give me some help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{\epsilon}^{1} f(x)dx \leq \int_{\epsilon}^{1}x f'(x)dx-f(1)$ since $\epsilon f(\epsilon) \geq 0$. Hence, $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx \leq \int_{0}^{1}x f'(x)dx-f(1)<\infty$.

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't realize I can obtain what I need from this simple estimation!